# Grails Session scope for service not working as expected

Tags: grails, grails-services

I'm making a web app that stores reports of various types as domain objects, so I have a domain object `HeadOfHousehold` which contains name data, and references to other domain objects such as the `reports`, `addresses`, and any dependants.  I am trying to build a list of recently viewed/created `HeadOfHousehold` objects.  After multiple Google searches, and scouring the manual, it appeared that a service would be an appropriate solution.  So I created `ClientListService`:

```
@Transactional
class ClientListService {
    static scope = "session"
    String message // right now I'll be happy to just see the same message across 
                  // pages I can add a list and manipulate it later.
}
```

I thought I could then reference it in my various controllers, and it would persist Something like this:

```
def clientListService

def index(){
    hasSearched = false
    clientListService = new ClientListService(message: "Hello")
    [errorMessage: params.errorMessage, clients:clientListService]

}
```

Which should be available in a later controller:

```
class HeadOfHouseHoldController {
     def clientListService
    def index() {

        [customer: HeadOfHousehold.get(params.id), clients: clientListService]
    }//...
```

However when I try to get the message, it appears as if the object is null. 
From my index.gsp:

```
***************${clients?.message}********************
```

So I don't know if I am not defining session properly (I'm not doing anything special to do so), if I'm misunderstanding how the session scope works, or something else.  I do see the proper message on the original page which has defined the object, however I don't see it on any subsequent pages.

Also, I'm not sure if this is the proper way to go about this; right now all I really need is the list of `HeadOfHouseholds` that I would need (so I can add to the list from other pages), however I can see possibly adding other logic and items into such a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you understood the `session` scope correctly. Each Spring bean with a [session scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-global-session) is bound to the HTTP session.

But your first controller listing does it all wrong. You are not supposed to instantiate the service class yourself. This is what Spring (Grails) does.

```
class FooController {
   def clientListService // gets autowired by Grails/Spring

   def index(){
       hasSearched = false
       clientListService.message = 'Hello' // only assign a String value to the service
       [errorMessage: params.errorMessage, clients:clientListService]
   }
}
```

This means you cannot not do something like

```
clientListService = new ClientListService(message: "Hello")
```

and expect your code to work. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, so grails needs to instantiate the class because it is attaching it to the current session is that right?  

Also working through this, I found I could just bind a list directly to the `session` object, and access what I need that way. Is one technique preferred over another?